# Tests pass when test running individually but not pass when run the whole class

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

When i run test individually everythink is ok, but when i run the whole test class, i got this 3 exception in 3 method which i run, its: getPersonById / savePerson / deleteById . The remain method run success

getPersonById method:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

--

savePerson method:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
> com.entity.Person with id 1

--

deleteById method:

> org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class
> com.entity.Person entity with id 1 exists!

Code:

```
package com.repository;

import com.entity.Person;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;


@DataJpaTest
class PersonRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    private Person person;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        person = new Person();

        person.setId(1L);
        person.setName("Test1");
        person.setSurname("Test1_2");
        person.setDate_of_birth("18 Years");

    }


    @AfterEach
     void tearDown() {
        personRepository.deleteAll();
    }




    @Test
    public void shouldCheckIfPersonExists(){

        personRepository.save(person);
        assertTrue(personRepository.existsById(1L));


    }


    @Test
    public void getAllPerson() {

        personRepository.save(person);
        List<Person> list = personRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(1, list.size());


    }


    @Test
        public void getPersonById() {



        personRepository.save(person);

        Optional<Person> byId = personRepository.findById(1L);

        assertEquals(person.getId(), byId.get().getId());
        assertEquals(person.getName(), byId.get().getName());



    }


    @Test
    public void savePerson() {


        personRepository.save(person);
        Person newPerson = personRepository.getById(1L);

        assertEquals(person.toString(), newPerson.toString());


    }

    @Test
    public void deleteById() {

        personRepository.save(person);
        personRepository.deleteById(1L);
        assertFalse(personRepository.existsById(1L));

    }

}
```

Comment: That all depends on what PersonRepository is, doesn't it?

Comment: `package com.repository;

import com.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {



}`   Its the whole PersonRepository interface.

Answer (score 0):

It probably fails because you use `save()` method which is not destined to save entities with ID set. This method automatically generates ID and that's why it's not always 1.

Comment: `@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;`  I use this in my Entity  class. And when i remove save() i transfer creating ID to my db, but it still doesnt work. Or you mean somethink else?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).